# Is isNaN() really necessary?

Tags: javascript, nan

According to the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)<sup>1</sup> regarding `isNaN` (emphasis mine):

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (== and ===) to determine whether a value is NaN or not, because both NaN == NaN and NaN === NaN evaluate to false. *Hence, the necessity of an isNaN function*.

However, since `NaN` is the only value in JavaScript that will compare unequal to itself, it is in fact possible to rely on the strict equality operator to determine, **unequivocally**, wheter a value is `NaN` or not:

```js
const value = NaN;
console.log(value === value)
```

That said, what's the explanation for that MDN sentence?

---

<sup>PS: I do understand that MDN is not an official documentation (that would be ECMA) and that much like a wiki anyone can edit it. Even so, it's a very reliable source.</sup>

<sup>1: That paragraph has been edited after this question was posted, [as mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289840/is-isnan-really-necessary#comment113684779_64289852) by the answerer.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, having a built-in `isNaN` function isn't necessary. `isNaN` is just for convenience's sake. Sure, one could manually do:

```
const isNaN = arg => arg !== arg
```

for every script you wanted to perform such an operation in, but it'd be tedious.

Or, without the function, consider reading code like:

```
if (parsedNumber !== parsedNumber) {
  // It's NaN
}
```

That'd look *really* weird, and it's in programmers' best interests to have code be as readable as possible.

Comment: I do understand that, thanks. I'm confused about that specific MDN claim. Therefore, since it's just for convenience (I also think so), can we agree that the sentence is just plain wrong?

Comment: Yeah. Pretty sure it's meant to be read - "You cannot use `someVar === NaN` to test." I'll edit it to clarify

Comment: I reckon you nailed, that's probably what happened here: the author probably meant *"you cannot compare a variable with NaN"*, but he/she forgot that one can compare a variable with itself, and therefore the strict equality operator **can** be used to unequivocally determine if a variable is `NaN`...